# "Дай Бог каждому": тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Увидела в интернете "вопрос за засыпку": "Талант у него () дай Бог каждому". Я бы поставила тире. А как правильно?

Comment: >А как правильно?
   
А есть варианты? 
Или "помощь зала"?

Comment: Там правильного ответа на тот момент не было))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интуиция Вас не подвела: нужно тире.Это классический пример к правилу:

Тире ставится при сказуемом, выраженном фразеологическим оборотом: Мой брат - мастер на все руки; Талант у него - дай бог каждому; а также любым устойчивым сочетанием: Мать от радости прослезилась, а отец - хоть бы что! (Крут.); Сапожки - что тебе зеркало!     http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-021.htm

Answer (score 0):

Это сказуемое составное именное, именная часть выражена устойчивым оборотом, который заменяет собой прилагательное (велик, высок...), поэтому никакого знака не надо